# How to get live stream url from script

Tags: python, shell, video-streaming

I need to get the live stream url using a scripting language such as python or shell

eg: http://rt.com/on-air/

I can get the url by using a tool such as the network monitor on Firefox, but i need to be able to get it via a script

Answer (score 1):

After quick look on [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) documentation:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(requests.get('http://rt.com/on-air/', stream=True)) as r:
    # Do things with the response here.
```

If it doesn't help, please check [another way](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://rt.com/on-air/', stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():

    # filter out keep-alive new lines
    if line:
        # do some sort of things
```

Comment: Tx for the help. I need to get this link from the web page http://streams.octoshape.net/streamlink/russiatoday/live/ch1_480p, But I cant find it within the source

Comment: so you have problems with XML parsing?

Comment: No i mean I dont see it within the source at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify it in the source of the page. It is pretty much the same as using the network tool from FF.
For python you can use beautifulsoup to parse the page and get more info out of it... or a simple regex.